# Overflow error for Long data type

Tags: ms-access, vba

I get an Overflow error for `(1000 * 60)` but when I change it to `(60000)` it works just fine. Why is 1000 * 60 not the same as 60000? This is what im working with.

```
Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long
Dim NowTick As Long
Dim SaveTick As Long

Public Sub ToolACCLooper()
SaveTick = GetTickCount + (1000 * 60)

Do
    NowTick = GetTickCount
    DoEvents
    If SaveTick <= NowTick Then
         ActiveWorkbook.Save
         SaveTick = GetTickCount + (1000 * 60)
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numbers `1000` and `60` are both `Integer` unless you specifically say otherwise.  Multiplying two `Integer` values gives an `Integer` result, but `60000` exceeds the maximum value that can be stored as `Integer`, therefore you get an overflow error.

You can force the multiplication to work by making at least one of them a `Long`, e.g. `1000& * 60`, or `CLng(1000) * 60` would work, because a `Long` multiplied by an `Integer` returns a `Long`.

Comment: Thank you for the awesome answer and solution.