# Why does long l = 1000 * 60 cause overflow?

Tags: vb6

I have this line:

```
    Dim l&
    l = 1000 * 60 '1 min
```

It throws an overflow error.

Why is that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895816/vb6-overflow-error-with-large-integers

Comment: I don't think that's a perfect dupe as in this case the variable is defined as a long, the other case it was an integer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overflow error for Long data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44492345/overflow-error-for-long-data-type)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vb's Help says:

> You attempt to use a number in a calculation, and that number is
> coerced into an integer, but the result is larger than an integer. For
> example:
>
> ```
> Dim x As Long
> x = 2000 * 365   ' Error: Overflow
> ```
>
> To work around this situation, type the number, like this:
>
> ```
> Dim x As Long
> x = CLng(2000) * 365
> ```

Comment: The abbreviated form `2000& * 365` also works, and can be used as well.  The `&` coerces the number to be a long, and Long * Int is multiplied as long.

Comment: Yes. I know. I never ever used the short form in all the years I used VB from version 3 to 6! That was just a straight copy and paste from the MSDN Help.

Comment: The short form is probably converted to a `Long` at compile time. The long form will almost certainly be converted to a `Long` at run time, i.e. it will run slightly slower, as well as the code being a little longer.